# How to export limited rows from synchronized database from marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-export

We've few synchronized databases integrated in marketing cloud from sales cloud like "Lead" , "Enquiry", "Opportunity" etc. This tables are huge and ranges around 2 GB.

I want to export only some sample data and not the complete table through browser download. Haven't found any option to export limited number of rows.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to utilize a SQL query to pull your X rows into a separate DE and then export that.

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 /* Only pulls the first 2k records */
   EmailAddress
   ,FirstName
   ,...... /* The rest of your attributes */
FROM ENT.[yourSyncDE]
ORDER BY NEWID() /* This makes it fairly random */
```

You then push this to another DE that has all the required attributes you want to pass. Then you go into this DE and export it as you wanted.

Comment: Hi Gortonington, this is the only option available right now in marketing cloud, but my object table (for example Lead object) contains more than 200 fields. Making a data extension for such a huge database is in itself is a big task. Salesforce should provide some preview feature for sql query and from where export is also possible upto some row or size limit.

Comment: I believe the preview option is on their list of features for future releases, but no projected dates for release yet

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many options when it comes to setting up the Data Stream for Synchronised Data Extensions unfortunately, like setting a specific row limit.

The least you can do is configure the Synchronisation to either:

**1)** Synchronise only records created after X date. With this you could limit it to be created from October 2018 for an example. This is not going to get you a specific amount, but more of a ballpark which you can check first with SF reports.

**2)** Synchronise *only* records with a specific field value. You can use some existing field to determine which records you synchronise over, or alternatively you can create a new field (example - checkbox "MC-Synch") and mass-update the exact amount of records you would like to get synchronised over.

Here's where you can pick **one** of the options:

[image]